# Html elements which are after select/ng-options are not visible when page is loaded

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using below snippet, I see just select (dropdown's; array of phones is of size 3, so I am seeing 3 select elements), but I don't see any other element put after it (like phone.name, paragraph tags etc). Could not understand why the elements after select element are not displayed. Can you please help in answering this doubt.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones track by phone.id">
            <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names" />
            <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
            <p> {{phone.id}}</p>
            [ <a href="" ng-click="RemoveFromPhonesArray(phone.id)">X</a> ]
            <p> index is {{$index}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: No errors are seen on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `select` is an pair tag so you need to use a closing tag `<select ng-options=...></select>`.

Comment: Thanks, when i paired it, it worked, i can see elements after select.

Comment: @vrreddy1234 happy to help. I'd appreciate if you could select this as the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, i did.. thanks for quick answer. I have one another doubt, i would like to see all elements present under ng-repeat on same line i.e select, paragraph etc present inside ng-repeat to be on same line. how should the above snippet be looked like.. can you please answer.

Comment: Use an inline element instead of `<p>` like `<span>`